# i want to send an email via tsend email component in talend

Tags: etl, talend

Hello i want to send an email via tsend email component in talend.i configured the component like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67wq8.png)

But its still gives me the error

```
Exception in component tSendMail_1 (EmailJob)
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1462)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at local_project.emailjob_0_1.EmailJob.tSendMail_1Process(EmailJob.java:967)
    at local_project.emailjob_0_1.EmailJob.tFileInputProperties_1Process(EmailJob.java:705)
    at local_project.emailjob_0_1.EmailJob.runJobInTOS(EmailJob.java:1253)
    at local_project.emailjob_0_1.EmailJob.main(EmailJob.java:1102)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440)
    ... 11 more
[statistics] disconnected

Job EmailJob terminé à 17:51 14/11/2018. [Code sortie=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing `Connection reset` means basically, that the connection has been closed by the other end. There are many articles on this. You can read.

See 
[send-email-using-talend](https://help.talend.com/reader/Ok43Kg3ngFDpParZTRS4Tg/MyK~z4vo0uDqz8lRXAMq7w) for creating jobs in Talend for sending email. This should help.

Comment: The problem was that the antivirus was blocking the connection.So I desactivated it and its fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its connection closed problem. Please turn off *2-step verification* and *Allow less secure apps* on your mail account and check again.